# check out type of element，but i don't understand the 'return !!e'?

Tags: javascript

code

```
    <div id = 'd' class="dd">div test type of element ...</div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function isElement(e){
            console.log(e);
            console.log(!!e);
            return !!e && e.nodeType === 1;
        }
        console.log(isElement(document.getElementById('d')));
    </script>
```

i just want to check out type of element, but the return values that confuse me.

the meaning of  '!!e'??

why should i use '!!e'?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double logic not `!!` is popular technic to cast value from falsy or truthy to boolean `false` or `true` value.